# .htaccess http to https redirect loop issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect users to https://example.com when they enter http://example.com in the browser. I am using .htaceess to acheive the redirection. Problem is after adding below .htaccess to my site, browser(chrome) shows **This webpage has a redirect loop** . This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Please suggest me the solution

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: Is it in wordpress? if so then check your home link in wp_options table.

Comment: Core PHP site. I tried @Helping Hands answer too. But not working

Answer (score 0):

User below code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```